# How to make a background image on frame in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem i want to put a image as the background for this little converter can someone help me? I was looking online and on stackoverflow but none of the things i found would work with the class.

```
__author__ = 'apcs'
from tkinter import *


class FarenheitToCelsius(Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Farenheit To Celsius Conversion")
        self.grid()



        self.farenheitLabel = Label(self, text="Farenheit")
        self.farenheitLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.farVar = DoubleVar()
        self.farEntry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.farVar)
        self.farEntry.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.celsiusLabel = Label(self, text="Celsius")
        self.celsiusLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.celVar = DoubleVar()
        self.celEntry = Entry(self, textvariable=self.celVar)
        self.celEntry.grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.button = Button(self,
                             text="Convert to Celsius",
                             command=self.convertToFarenheit)
        self.button2 = Button(self,
                              text="Convert to Farenheit",
                              command=self.convertToCelsius)
        self.button.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=1)
        self.button2.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=1)


    def convertToFarenheit(self):
        fare = self.farVar.get()
        cels = (fare - 32) * 5 / 9
        self.celVar.set(cels)

    def convertToCelsius(self):
        cel = self.celVar.get()
        far = cel * 9 / 5 + 32
        self.farVar.set(far)


def main():
    FarenheitToCelsius().mainloop()


main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of at least three ways to do this:

1. Create an image in a label, and use `place` to put it in the frame. Then create all of the other widgets and use `pack` or `grid` as you normally would. Make sure you create the frame first, then the label with the image, then the children of the frame, so that the stacking order is correct.
2. Use a canvas instead of a frame, and use the [create_image](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method) method to add an image. Then you can pack/place/grid children as normal.
3. Instead of a frame, use a label as the container, and then pack/place/grid widgets into the label (yes, you can add children to a label widget).